# What exactly does this XPath expression do (count and here)?

Tags: xml, xpath

This is from the [XML Signature specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-c14nAlg):

```
<XPath xmlns:dsig="&dsig;">
count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature |
here()/ancestor::dsig:Signature[1]) >
count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature)</XPath>
```

The accompanying text says "An enveloped signature transform T removes the whole Signature element containing T from the digest calculation of the Reference element containing T." I don't have a working `here()` so I can't probe it. I think the text of the specification is a little loose. Consider the following scenario:

```
<saml2:Assertion ID="2">
 <ds:Signature ID="s1">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:Reference URI="#2">
    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms>
   </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
 <ds:Signature ID="s2">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:Reference URI="#2">
    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms>
   </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
 <ds:Signature  ID="s3">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:Reference URI="#2">
    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms>
   </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

With the active node being "s2", which `<ds:Signature>` nodes are removed?

The system XML library is [broken](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c32b1f5c7c476aa7a4391558d88b4adf178f3df7/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Xml/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Xml/Reference.cs#L268). I can't ask it.

Answer (score 0):

```
count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature |
        here()/ancestor::dsig:Signature[1]) >
      count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature)
```

The expression `count(X|Y) > count(X)` returns true if Y contains one or more nodes that are not included in X.

I think the `[1]` is entirely redundant. The expression is true if `here()` has an ancestor Signature that is not an ancestor-or-self of the context node.

As for what `here()` does, you'll have to get that from someone who knows the XML Signature spec.

The expression, where it appears in the XML Signature spec, is immediately followed by an explanation: "For each node of the document, the predicate expression is true if and only if the node-set containing the node and its Signature element ancestors does not include the enveloped Signature element containing the XPath expression". I'm not sure what part of that isn't clear...

Comment: Please synthesize not translate. I have a hunch that there's an intended way to do two enveloped signatures on the same node.

Comment: Wait a minute .. if `here()/ancestor::dsig:Signature` were entirely redundant then the expression would collapse to `count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature) > count(ancestor-or-self::dsig:Signature)` which is clearly never true.

Comment: No, I said the predicate `[1]` is redundant.